# Looking to extract individual user (@) mentions from a list of Tweets in an excel document

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of ~1000 tweets from a user I'm monitoring. I would like to be able to track how many *unique* user mentions (i.e., appearances of `@anyUserName`) are within the strings.

Each tweet is stored within a single cell.
I want to be able to extract the @variable-length string from the cell.

Been a couple of days at this, would appreciate any help.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Would you please add some detail? How is the data structured? What exactly do you want to do. What have you tried, why isn't it working? A sample example would be great as well.

Comment: Aim: To count the number of mentions from unique @mentions.

The data is single column strings of tweets including at least one variable length component starting with @.

I believe I need to put into a pivot table, add a column and extract just the @ (plus username component). I can then remove duplicates from that column and add up the uniques.

Comment: So you want to take the contents of a cell and extract every time an `@` appears and the characters after it *until you encounter a space*. Then you want to list these and count uniques? And each tween is in a single cell in a specific column? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry Raystafarian, I have added an image. You are quite correct. I wish to extract @ plus any text until I encounter a space. mentions are contained at various locations within a string of text ( a tweet). I'm stuck in how do I remove the variable length mention and insert into another separate column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, seeing your data, if you want to extract multiple @'s per tweet, you'd have to have one column per instance you are seaking:

`=IFERROR(MID($A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A2,"@","|",B$1)),IFERROR(FIND(" ",$A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A2,"@","|",B$1))),LEN($A2)+1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A2,"@","|",B$1))),"")`

Put this in B2, and copy down and over.

This looks overwhelming, but temporarity replaces the nth instance of @ with a different character (one that is unlikely to be used in a tweet, a pipe "|"), and then finds that location and the next space after.  If there is no space after, it handles the name being the last thing in the tweet.

In this example, your tweets are in column A starting in row 2 (assume header is row 1).  You can put this formula in B2 and copy to the right for as many columns as you need.  It is expecting your header to be which name to extract.  Like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Madball. 

I really appreciate the time you've taken to answer, but I wonder if you could clarify something. Do I change the instances of 'A1' to the cell I wish the MID command to seek? I really should be more au fait with the platform before EI start to carry out complex searches.

Comment: You put the formula in B1 and drag it down column B until the end of data in column A @Adam

Comment: REALLY appreciate this, thanks to both of you for the help!

Comment: @Adam please see changed answer, the first version did not handle multiple @s in a tweet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a VBA solution. Just paste the following code into a module (Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and go to  `Insert` >> `Module`). Select your list of tweets and execute (by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> from the VBA Editor window).

```vb
Sub getUniqueUsers()
Dim r As Range, users As Object, Tweets() As Variant, ns As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim rgx As Object, Matches As Object, M As Object, key As Variant
Set r = Selection
'Load tweets into array for fast processing
Tweets = r.Value
'create scripting objects
Set users = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
Set rgx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
rgx.MultiLine = True
rgx.Pattern = "(^| )(@[^ \t]+)"
'Check each tweet for user mentions with regular expression matching. Add all matches to dictionary.
For j = LBound(Tweets, 2) To UBound(Tweets, 2)
    For i = LBound(Tweets, 1) To UBound(Tweets, 1)
        Set Matches = rgx.Execute(Tweets(i, j))
        For Each M In Matches
            If Not users.exists(M.submatches.Item(1)) Then
                users.Add M.submatches.Item(1), M.submatches.Item(1)
            End If
        Next M
    Next i
Next j
'Output list to new sheet
Set ns = Worksheets.Add
ns.Name = "Unique User Mentions"
k = 1
For Each key In users
    ns.Range("A" & k).Value = key
    k = k + 1
Next key
End Sub
```

This code uses regular expression and dictionary scripting objects. It will find the user mentions in each tweet and store them in a dictionary. The dictionary is used to ensure uniqueness. Finally, the unique user mentions are printed in column A on a new sheet.